# Commutating Matrices, a question

Tags: linear-algebra

RE-EDITED:

I've come to conclusion that $e^{At}e^{Bt}=e^{Bt}e^{At}$ if:

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{k+j}}{k!j!}A^kB^j=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{k+j}}{k!j!}B^jA^k$

Does anyone have any idea how I can verify that it only is true if $AB=BA$?

Comment: Yes, just apply $AB=BA$ repeatedly in $A^xB^y$, you will get $B^yA^x$. An example $A^2B^2=A(AB)B=A(BA)B=(AB)(AB)=(BA)(BA)=B(AB)A=B(BA)A=B^2A^2.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using induction we have $AB=BA$. Also if $A^mB^n=B^nA^m$ we obtain$$A^{m+1}B^n=A.A^mB^n=AB^nA^m=B^nA^{m+1}$$similarly$$A^mB^{n+1}=B^{n+1}A^m$$and $$A^{m+1}B^{n+1}=B^{n+1}A^{m+1}$$which means that for all natural $l,k$ we have $$A^lB^k=B^kA^l$$

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. This made it possible to finish a proof I've been working on for the last 5 hours...

Comment: I'm happy for you. Wish you luck!!!

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{align}
A^x B^y &= \underbrace{A\cdots (A}_{x \text{ times}}\underbrace{B)\cdots B}_{y \text{ times}}\\
&= \underbrace{A\cdots (B}_{x \text{ times}}\underbrace{A)\cdots B}_{y \text{ times}}\\
&= \underbrace{A\cdots (A}_{x-1 \text{ times}}B)A\underbrace{B\cdots B}_{y-1 \text{ times}}\\
&= \underbrace{A\cdots (A}_{x-2 \text{ times}}B)AA\underbrace{B\cdots B}_{y-1 \text{ times}}\\
&= \ldots\\
&=B\underbrace{A\cdots A}_{x \text{ times}}\underbrace{B\cdots B}_{y-1 \text{ times}}\\ &= BA^xB^{y-1}.
\end{align}
Now repeat this $y-1$ more times.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.